# Image/Icon Rotation in a Tab using CSS3 Rotation

Tags: css, image-rotation

I wanted to create a Metro Style Website and want to add Buttons like in the following :

http://themeforest.net/item/metro-lab-responsive-metro-dashboard-template/full_screen_preview/5359122

When we hover over the 'New User', 'Sales' etc Tabs, the icons/Images in the tabs rotates, increases its size and looses opacity.

But I am not able to get the exact output.

You can see where I had reached at :

http://developer.nuevothoughts.com/jiteen/attendance/docs/#

I would appreciate any kind of Help in this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use transition timings...

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
```

The above is the CSS applied to the example site you gave.

Comment: Not happening much. Can you please provide me a working Jsfiddle Demo ?

Comment: It's your job to provide the JSfiddle, do that and I'll take a look but I'm not going to extract all of your code to make it.

Comment: Ok, got that. but can you please suggest me that I have 3 things :3 things at once : Scaling to 2.5, changing position to Right and Rotate. all at the same time. Now, when I had applied SCALE property, it scales and looses opacity but DOESN'T rotates.
If I comment SCALE, then ROTATE works.
How can I make these 2 properties work simultaneously ?

Comment: @user3127352 Please paste your code or post to fiddle, and we can hep you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.icon-rocket{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;

    }  

.icon-rocket:hover  
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: This one is working fine but I have 3 things at once : Scaling to 2.5, changing position to Right and Rotate. all at the same time.
Now, when I had applied SCALE property, it scales but doesn't rotates.
How can I make these 2 properties work simultaneously ?